# AngulaJS count filtered results matching multiple strings

Tags: angularjs

i'm new to AngularJS and start to get confident with the filtered method. What i want to achieve is just for view purpose.

```
<div ng-if="phase.status == 'active' || ((phase.contacts | filter:{status:'active'}).length == 0 && (phase.contacts | filter:{status:'waiting'}).length == 0)" class="">
```

so my goal is to check if there is any contact with the status on active or waiting.
thanks in advance.

Comment: First off, check your parentheses. You got a closing parenthesis after `{status: 'active'}` that doesn't have a matching opening parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry my fault, i just updated the code with the entire line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was on OR.
length method is working as expected after removing it.